# Looking for an explanation of unusual behavior in Divisors[] function

Tags: functions, warning-messages

I have defined the function that counts the number of square divisors of input integer x.  The function is

`NumberOfSquareDivisors[H_]:=Length[Select[Divisors[H],Not@*SquareFreeQ]];`

Now when computing the average number of square divisors cases at H = 10000000 I get

`N[Sum[NumberOfSquareDivisors[i],{i,1,10000000}]/10000000]`

`Divisors::argx: Divisors called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected.`

When tested for smaller values, say 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6 I get the proper sum.  So at 10^7 the Divisors function is claiming that it is called with zero arguments.  How can this occur?

Is this an error in Mathematica or something else?

I have tested this on two difference computers using the latest version of Mathematica.

Comment: does `SetSystemOptions["SymbolicSumThreshold" -> 10000000];
N[Sum[NumberOfSquareDivisors[i], {i, 1, 10000000}]/10000000]` work?

Comment: Yes that did work.  Now I am at work using the cloud and the calculation exceed my time limit, but this tells me that it was computing the sum without the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the length of the sum exceeds 10^6, [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum) will try to compute the result symbolically. This symbolic computation fails miserably for your function, generating errors. You can see this for smaller values by setting a system option:

```
SetSystemOptions["SymbolicSumThreshold"->1000];

Sum[NumberOfSquareDivisors[i],{i,1,1001}]
```

> Divisors::argx: Divisors called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected.

> 0

Clearly, trying to perform a symbolic sum of a user defined function is unlikely to work. You can avoid this by raising the threshold:

```
SetSystemOptions["SymbolicSumThreshold"->Infinity];

Sum[NumberOfSquareDivisors[i],{i,1,10^7}]
```

However, I don't have the patience to wait for this to finish. You can reset to the default with:

```
SetSystemOptions["SymbolicSumThreshold"->10^6];
```

Comment: That makes sense, however it was unexpected.  At least I get an error/warning condition.  I do use user defined functions with sums in many cases, however, the sum limits are usually small so I have not seen this condition until now.